# replace some special character with newline \n

Tags: python

I have a text file with numbers and symbols, i want to delete some character of them and to put new line.
for example the text file is like that:

```
00004430474314-3","100004430474314-3","1779803519-3","100003004929477-3","100006224433874-3","1512754498-3","100003323786067
```

i want the output to be like that:

```
00004430474314
100004430474314
100003004929477
1779803519
100006224433874
1512754498
100003323786067
```

i tred to replace `-3","` with `\n` by this code but it does not work. any help?

```
import re
import collections
s = re.findall('\w+', open('text.txt').read().lower())
print(s.replace("-3","",">\n"))
```

Comment: You don't need Python for this. Any text editor can do a simple find-and-replace like this quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re.findall` is useless here.

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    contents = infile.read()
    contents = contents.replace('-3","', '\n')
    print(contents)
```

Another problem with your code is that you seem to think that `"-3",""` is a string containing `-3","`. This is not the case. Python sees a second `"` and interprets that as the end of the string. You have a comma right afterward, which makes python consider the second bit as the second parameter to `s.replace()`.

What you really want to do is to tell python that those double quotes are part of the string. You can do this by manually escaping them as follows:

```
some_string_with_double_quotes = "this is a \"double quote\" within a string"
```

You can also accomplish the same thing by defining the string with single quotes:

```
some_string_with_double_quotes = 'this is a "double quote" within a string'
```

Both types of quotes are equivalent in python and can be used to define strings. This may be weird to you if you come from a language like C++, where single quotes are used for characters, and double quotes are used for strings.

Answer (score 0):

First I think that the s object is not a *string* but a *list* and if you try to make is a *string* (s=''.join(s) for example) you are going to end with something like this:

```
0000443047431431000044304743143177980351931000030049294773100006224433874315127544983100003323786067
```

Where replace() is useless.

I would change your code to the following (tested in python 3.2)

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('text.txt')]
line=''.join(lines)
cl=line.replace("-3\",\"","\n")
print(cl)
```